# Merge array elements with same id values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the follow array in PHP. 
Id and Total key are the same for the same Id values.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id]    => 1
            [total] => 100
            [line]  => books
            [value] => 10
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id]    => 1
            [total] => 100
            [line]  => cars
            [value] => 50
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id]    => 1
            [total] => 100
            [line]  => cover
            [value] => 30
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id]    => 2
            [total] => 80
            [line]  => books
            [value] => 5
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id]    => 2
            [total] => 80
            [line]  => cover
            [value] => 35
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [id]    => 2
            [total] => 80
            [line]  => cars
            [value] => 40
        )
```

)

And I would like to merge Line and Value element inside an array.
To illustrate the result I am looking is the follow array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id]      => 1
            [total]   => 100
            [details] => Array
               (
                   [0] => Array
                      (
                         [line]  => books
                         [value] => 10
                      )
                   [1] => Array
                      (
                         [line]  => cars
                         [value] => 50
                      )
                   [2] => Array
                      (
                         [line]  => cover
                         [value] => 30
                      )
               ) 
        )                      

    )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id]      => 2
            [total]   => 80
            [details] => Array
               (
                   [0] => Array
                      (
                         [line]  => books
                         [value] => 5
                      )
                   [1] => Array
                      (
                         [line]  => cars
                         [value] => 35
                      )
                   [2] => Array
                      (
                         [line]  => cover
                         [value] => 40
                      )
               ) 
        )                      
    )
```

I am working with PHP. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: simple foreach loop will work - you need to at least try something

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post what you have attempted thus far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

well bored enough to do your job\homework for you:

```
$out=array();
foreach($array as $x){
  $out[$x['id']]['id']=$x['id'];
  $out[$x['id']]['total']=$x['total'];
  $out[$x['id']]['details'][]=array('line'=>$x['line'],'value'=>$x['value']);
}
```

NOTES:

- use id as the out key, could of added our own, but this will work
  fine.
- id and total will be overwritten on each loop (per key) but that's no big deal
- line\value are incremented in to there own details array

Comment: lol, you are completely right, Sorry, I have so many thing in my mind that I choose to post my problem.

PS. This is my first post, I am not sure how to mark this question as a correct answer.

Comment: @user3216926 under the votes on the left of the question there should be a check mark, click to it goes green: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I like the other kind of green $$$$$

Comment: @Fred-ii- you getting moldy there

Comment: That's what age does. Sitting by the brook on an old weary rock, sure doesn't help neither. Whoever said *"a rolling stone gathers no moss"*, didn't have a computer.